# Are there any ways to get a list of all controller actions in all of your src bundles

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

**Backstory:**

Using Symfony 2.2.1

I have created a custom annotation for permissions that attach to a controller action. EX:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="lg.user.usermanager.index")
 * @Template
 * @Permissions(perm="lg.user.usermanager.index", desc="Lists all users")
 */
public function indexAction(){ ... }
```

I have setup a listener that attaches to all requests and checks that a user has the permissions to access that action. For example if a user has been granted the "lg.user.usermanager.*" permission then that user will have access to all actions that match that pattern. lg.user.usermanager.create, lg.user.usermanager.index, lg.user.usermanager.edit would all match that.

With that in mind the route parameters also get checked. So

```
/**
 * ...
 * @Permissions(perm="lg.user.usermanager.edit", desc="Allows for a particular user to be editted")
 */
 public function editAction(User $user)
```

in order for a user to be able to edit the user "test" they would need to have the permission "lg.user.usermanager.edit.test" or "lg.user.usermanager.edit.*"

**Problem:**

Right now i have to manually enter all of the users or groups permission nodes. I am trying to come up with a way that i can select the nodes from a list of available node. I have written a command that is very primitive and it loops through all my files and using regex matches a pattern that allows me to pull out the node and the description and update that into a table.

The issue with this is that it doesnt account for possible "*" nodes and it also doesnt account for all the actions additional parameters.

**The Possible Solution**

What i would like to do is to be able to somehow get a list(dynamically) of all controllers within the application and then use the Annotation reader to get both my annotations for permissions and the addition route params that im checking against. With those i feel i could devise a solution that would allow me to list the available nodes.

However if you know of or would like to recommend a better solution i am open to anything at this point.

Answer (score 3):

**I know it's a long time ago, but maybe it's helpful to other users:**

Altough there is no offical way to get the controllers, you can use the following code to get all controllers:

```
$bundles = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.bundles');
$controllers = [];
foreach ($bundles as $bundle) {
    $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($bundle);
    $controllerDirectory = dirname($reflection->getFileName()) . '/Controller';
    if (file_exists($controllerDirectory)) {
        $d = dir($controllerDirectory);
        while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {

            if (preg_match("/^([A-Z0-9-_]+Controller).php/i", $entry, $matches)) {                        
                $controllers[] = ['fileName' => $controllerDirectory. '/'. $entry, 'class' => $reflection->getNamespaceName() . '\Controller\\' . $matches[1]];
            }
        }
        $d->close();
    }
}
print_r($controllers);
```